# Exact Online Refresh-token Header generates Java Exception (Exact Online, OAuth)

Tags: exception, response, apex, apex-code, exact-online

I'm sending an OAuth callout to https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token
When the Refresh Token is expired Exact Online returns an invalid messages. The response that is returned contains 2 WWW-Authentication headers (where 1 is blank).

[image: Example of header]

Java request handling does not accept this and throws an exception;
Since Salesforce doesn't handle low-level Java exceptions it is impossible to handle authentication responses with empty WWW-Authentication headers.

A discussion around this issue handling empty WWW-Authentication headers:
http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/jira-Created-CXF-4318-OAuthRequestFilter-generates-an-empty-WWW-Authenticate-header-td5707908.html

What I would like to know is:

1. Get in touch with someone from the EOL API team to fix this bug
2. Is there anyone who knows how to handle a Java exception in Apex

Comment: What is the actual problem description? The image and error are missing. Can you explain what you have tried? PS. You can ask questions to Exact Support related to API but unless there is a partnership agreement the depth is limited so you should phrase the question very precise.

Comment: If you expect an answer from the EOL API team, you should contact Exact support.

Comment: This is my attempt to reach that team. I know one of the members is active here.

Comment: No, there are no Exact Online support employees active here as far as I know @MarcoPietersen